# Fibonacci procedure in Java, sequencing

Tags: sequence, procedure, fibonacci, bluej

I am currently trying to figure out this question right now in regards to a Fibonacci sequence. It is fairly straight forward but I don't know what i can't get it. Apologize beforehand for my incompetence.

My current code, I know it's completely wrong, it doesn't even compile.. I'm so lost can someone please explain it to me

```
public static void fib(int n)
{
    int neW = 1;
    int next = 1;
    int old = neW - next;
    while (neW <= n)
    {
        neW = next + old;
        old = next;
        next = neW;
        System.out.println(neW);
    }

}
```

My current code output compared to the correct one;

Comment: Why are you returning neW when you're outputting the value within the function?

Comment: Ahh yea don't mind the new i just removed it now, is their anything else i can change?

Comment: I'd update your question to reflect the change in your code. It also seems that the code on the left of your output starts at 1 and not 0.

Answer (score 0):

On further investigation into your screenshot it seems like calling the function `fib(n)` should return n number of values and **not** up to that value. We don't tend to write code when we know it's an assignment however it seems that you missed a bit with the question and your code almost checks out... So here's my theory of a solution, but I cannot guarantee that it works.

```
public static void fib(int b)
    {
    int n = 0;
    int neW = 1;
    int next = 1;
    int old = neW - next;
    while (n <= b)
    {
        System.out.println(neW);
        neW = next + old;
        old = next;
        next = neW;
        n++;
    }
}
```

Something like that should do the trick.

Comment: Everything is right now except the extra line of numbers and the missing line of numbers for some reasons.
http://puu.sh/84BrV.png

Comment: I've updated my answer to put `System.out.println(neW)` first (which should solve the problem) but still, you're almost there and I'd hate for you to get into the trap of relying on us to complete your assignments :). Try it, if it doesn't work I'll gladly help out.

Comment: Ahh it should be fine, it's not an assignment as well, more like homework. Started for statements, do while and all that recently but i didn't understand the fibonacci concept with the for.

Comment: The for statement is really easy, you're passing it a start, end and increment values so in effect you're saying "Starting at `a`, for each iteration of this loop, increment by `b` until you reach the number `c`". `for(a=0;a<=c;a+b)`

Comment: @user3424841 don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if you feel that it's answered your question.

Comment: The elements of the Fibonacci sequence before its start are ...,-3,2,-1,1,0,1,1,2,3,5,... (see the pattern?), so you might also try to initialize the recursion with 1,0 so that the first computed numbers are 1,1,2,3,...

Comment: That's a good point, you need two seed values (1,0 in your case as @LutzL has pointed out).

Answer (score 0):

there's a couple of things about your code that confuse me, but this is how I would do it:

```
public static void fib(int n)
{
    int current = 0;
    int old = 1;
    int new = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i = i+1)
    {
        new = current + old;
        old = current;
        current = new;
        System.out.println(current);
    }

}
```

Comment: Ahh yes this solved the issue, cleared up my understanding very nicely thank you!!

Comment: If this helped please drop me a tick ;)